# Did the Python developers ever explain why they made such "obvious" breaking changes between two minor versions?

Tags: python

I read this comment today:

> When Python decides to add a "direction" parameter to sort() they do something like this:
>
> 3.2.7: sort(list)
>
> 3.2.8: sort(direction, list)
>
> You can't upgrade from 3.2.7 to 3.2.8 without breaking things, because there is a new parameter. Here's how Peel (and all sane languages) add a "direction" parameter:
>
> Perl 1.2.1: sort(thing)
>
> Perl 1.2.2: sort (thing, direction=ascending)
>
> In the new version, if you don't pass the argument to specify new optional behavior, you get the old behavior by default! That way things don't break.

It's not the first time I hear about this, but it seems really strange. Can somebody explain this decision once and for all? Surely it must have been motivated by some sort of reasoning, and not just "break things on purpose"?

I understand that things will (almost) inevitably break eventually or with major version changes, but this really seems like they *intended* it. Plus it was a *minor* version?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while some implementations of Python are open source, this question not about the open source nature of Python.

Comment: @PhillipKendall, perhaps a better match for StackOverflow.

Comment: This just doesn't sound right. Python has a `sorted` function that receives an iterable, and a `list` has a `sort`. Neither of them have a "direction" argument. Where did you see this comment? can you link to a source?

Comment: "Plus it was a minor version" - The change that you make between so-called "minor" versions is really up to you.  There is the so-called [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) specification, but in practice, projects do not really follow the rules of this consistently, if at all.